# How to read .mdf file in node js

Tags: node.js, mdf

I have one .mdf file. I wanted to read it and convert it to JSON file.
Where .mdf is Primary database data file.

I tried [mdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdf) npm package but, it did not work.

Please let mke know if thee is any other way to read .mdf file.

Comment: `.mdf` files are typically **SQL Server** database files

Comment: I will upload the file from UI then I have to convert that schema to json.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to create database from .mdf file** then use `mssql` driver to use it with the node (use of `mssql` driver: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/access-sql-server-in-nodejs) .

Creating database from `.mdf` file:

```
--SQL Script
Create database dbname 
On 
(   
Filename= 'path where you copied .mdf files',   
Filename ='path where you copied .ldf log' --Optional
)
For attach;
```

**OR** follow the steps below:

- First put the `.mdf` and `.ldf` file into `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\` folder
- Then go to SQL Server Management Studio, right-click “Databases” and click the “Attach” option to open the attach databases dialog box
- Click the “Add” button to open and locate database files from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\` folder
- Click the "OK" button. SQL Server Management Studio loads the database from the `.MDF` file.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, But I am not looking for this. I want read this file from node itself without any database.